# How to connect sql server with swift

Tags: sql-server, xcode, swift

I'm working now on an application for iOS (using swift), the database is already exist in SQL Server.
How I will use it and connect with it? Do i need a web service to do that?

thanks all .

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended to use a web service since having the application talk directly to the database means you need to include the SQL Credentials in the binary and anyone with a copy of the application can get them and do whatever they wish in the database. From a security point of view, this is bad.

The correct approach is to have a web server which will host an "API" -- a web application that will receive HTTP requests from the app and translate them to database queries and then will return the response in another format, such as JSON.

However, you need to be careful. This web services must use HTTPS and must first validate the input in order to protect against attacks such as [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).